# Find the parent key in array during recursive iteration

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Consider an array structure like this

```
[DVTTISEGA] => Array
        (
            [attr] => Array
                (
                    [DepartureDateTime] => 2014-03-17T06:15:00
                    [ArrivalDateTime] => 2014-03-17T10:50:00
                    [RPH] => 1
                    [FlightNumber] => 4376
                    [ResBookDesigCode] => U
                    [NumberInParty] => 4
                    [Status] => 36
                    [E_TicketEligibility] => Eligible
                    [DepartureDay] => Mon
                    [Distance] => 6197
                    [DateChangeNbr] => 0
                )

            [DepartureAirport] => Array
                (
                    [attr] => Array
                        (
                            [LocationCode] => MRS
                            [CodeContext] => IATA
                            [Terminal] => MP2
                        )

                )

            [ArrivalAirport] => Array
                (
                    [attr] => Array
                        (
                            [LocationCode] => DKR
                            [CodeContext] => IATA
                        )

                )

            [OperatingAirline] => Array
                (
                    [value] => ML
                    [attr] => Array
                        (
                            [FlightNumber] => 4376
                        )

                )

            [Equipment] => Array
                (
                    [attr] => Array
                        (
                            [AirEquipType] => 735       
                        )

                )

        )
```

There are two `LocationCode`. One inside parent array with key `DepartureAirport` and other inside `ArrivalAirport`. I have to store `LocationCode` in separate variables depending upon the parent keys. I am traversing the array recursively with the code:

```
function arrayTraverse($unserializedarray){
        foreach ($unserializedarray as $key => $value) {
            print "$key {\n";
                if(is_array($value)){
                    arrayTraverse($value);
                }
                else{
                    print "    $key => $value\n";
                }
            print "}\n";
        }
    }
```

Now in this code how can I assign the `LocationCode` to different variables depending upon the different parent keys that I mentioned?

Comment: Whenever you recurse, pass `$key` in as a second parameter. To make the initial call possible make the second parameter optional with a default `null` value.

Comment: @Jon: I understood your point, can you provide the code hints where should I be assigning the variable in which condition check?

Answer (score 0):

Pass path you've gone in array consisting of all keys as second argument to your function.
Now you can check history of keys that led you to current value.

```
function arrayTraverse( $unserializedarray, $path = array() ){
        foreach ($unserializedarray as $key => $value) {
            print "$key {\n";
                if(is_array($value)){
                    $path[] = $key;
                    arrayTraverse( $value, $path );
                }
                else{
                    print "    $key => $value\n";
                }
            print "}\n";
        }
    }
```

Or you can access the values without traversing array:

```
$departureAirportCode = $unserializedarray[ 'DVTTISEGA' ][ 'DepartureAirport' ][ 'attr' ][ 'LocationCode' ];
$arrivalAirportCode = $unserializedarray[ 'DVTTISEGA' ][ 'ArrivalAirport' ][ 'attr' ][ 'LocationCode' ];
```

Comment: But there are many instances not just the `LocationCode` for which I have to do the same.

Comment: Added alternative access without traversing. Hope it'll help.